# How do you know if your github golang repo is being used?

Tags: go, github, dependencies

I have an API client written in go. It's on github at the moment with about 4 stars, but I have no idea whether there are other developers using this package.

There's nothing listed if you go to the repository's `Insights->Dependency Graph`. I don't think that this is enabled for go projects.

What's the best way to **find out whether a golang package is being imported by another golang package/application?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really tell what private projects use your repo.

For public modules, you may use [`go.dev`](https://go.dev/). Go to [`pkg.go.dev`](https://pkg.go.dev/), enter your package import path, then click on the "Imported By" tab.